# Operation not allowed when the object is closed in VB6

Tags: sql, vb6

I know it's kind of old, but I am developing an application on VB6.
I can't undestand why I am getting this error.

```
DSN = "DatabaseInfo"
    
Dim Prod As Variant, Pal As Variant, Row As Long

If Grid.DataRowCnt > 0 Then
    For Row = 1 To Grid.DataRowCnt
        Grid.GetText 1, Row, Prod 
        Grid.GetText 11, Row, Pal
            
        Query = "SET NOCOUNT ON UPDATE myTable SET Pal='" & Pal & "'WHERE RTRIM(Prod)='" & Prod & "'"

        rsReg.Open Query, DSN, adOpenStatic
        Set rsReg= Nothing
    Next Row 
End If
rsReg.Close
MsgBox "You've done it!", vbInformation
```

I even tried to use the `SET NOCOUNT ON`, but it still doesn't work.
Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: What line is the error on? How do `Grid` and `rsReg` get instantiated and passed?

Comment: When debugging the error is here: rsReg.Close @Absinthe
It will go through all the rows, but when it closes the for cycle, it stops on the rsReg.Close

Comment: Once you exit the loop, rsReg = Nothing so the rsReg.Close will be a problem.

Comment: So how can I solve it? @BrianMStafford

Comment: You don't need to set it to nothing until the end of the sub

Comment: I removed that line of code `Set rsReg= Nothing`, but it keeps returning the same message. @Absinthe

Comment: You don't need to use a RecordSet in this case.  You could use a Command object instead.

Comment: Could you give me an example? @BrianMStafford

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to introduce the overhead of a RecordSet.  A better way of implementing this is with a Command object.  You should also use Parameters to make the command more simple and to avoid various security issues:

```
  DSN = "DatabaseInfo"
      
  Dim Prod As Variant, Pal As Variant, Row As Long
  Dim CM As ADODB.Command
  
  If Grid.DataRowCnt > 0 Then
      For Row = 1 To Grid.DataRowCnt
          Grid.GetText 1, Row, Prod
          Grid.GetText 11, Row, Pal
              
          Set CM = New ADODB.Command
          Set CM.ActiveConnection = "your connection"
          CM.CommandType = adCmdText
          CM.CommandText = "UPDATE myTable SET Pal = ? WHERE RTRIM(Prod) = ?"
          CM.Parameters.Append CM.CreateParameter("@Pal", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Pal)
          CM.Parameters.Append CM.CreateParameter("@Prod", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Prod)
          CM.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
      Next Row
  End If
  
  MsgBox "You've done it!", vbInformation
```